# Adding a button in forms available in Alfresco Activiti

Tags: alfresco, activiti

Is it possible to add a button(which performs a search operation) in the forms created via Forms Editor of Alfresco Activiti ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to search? And where abouts in the form do you want the button to appear? If you can post some more details or ideally a screenshot to give some context then that would help.

Comment: @Sunita, Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The operation of a form field depends on the type of control template (FTL) you add to the form field. E.G. If you would like to search for a person, you can use the authority.ftl control template.

```
<field id="mymodel:author">
    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/authority.ftl" />
</field>
```

Other templates exist in this path: /org/alfresco/components/form/controls/ or you can make your own custom control.